# ERROR [Experience Forms]: The SMTP host was not specified

Tags: sitecore-forms

I am using Sitecore 10.3, try to use the send mail action in Sitecore forms, I have modified the SMTP Settings in `Sitecore.EDS.Providers.CustomSMTP.Sync.config` as the below

[image]

and in web config

```
<add key="eds:define" value="CustomSMTP" />
<add key="exmEnabled:define" value="yes" />
```

and I tested the connection and it is working

[image]

but when I submitted the form the mail not sent and I see error in logs `"ERROR [Experience Forms]: The SMTP host was not specified."`

but I can not figure out what is wrong or missing, any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two Solutions for that

The First One is : option "Service email campaign" need to be checked on the "EMAIL EXPERIENCE MANAGER" - "Campaign creation" - "Delivery"Tab

[image]

The second Option is :
to set consent Field on your "send Email" action

Answer (score 0):

`Send mail` action is not using EXM settings.

It's using the following settings from `<sitecore><settings>` section of your configuration:

```
<setting name="MailServer" value="" />
<setting name="MailServerUserName" value="" />
<setting name="MailServerPassword" value="" />
<setting name="MailServerPort" value="" />
```

Make sure that you create a patch file which sets correct values here.

Patch file like this one should do the trick:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/" >
  <sitecore>

      <settings>
          <setting name="MailServer">
              <patch:attribute name="value" value="..." />
          </setting>
          <setting name="MailServerPort">
              <patch:attribute name="value" value="..." />
          </setting>
          <setting name="MailServerPassword">
              <patch:attribute name="value" value="......" />
          </setting>
          <setting name="MailServerUserName">
              <patch:attribute name="value" value="..." />
          </setting>
      </settings>
  </sitecore>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify also these settings :

```
        <setting name=“MailServer” value=“localhost” />
        <!--  MAIL SERVER USER
                If the SMTP server requires login, enter the user name in this setting
          -->
        <setting name=“MailServerUserName” value=“” />
        <!--  MAIL SERVER PASSWORD
                If the SMTP server requires login, enter the password in this setting
          -->
        <setting name=“MailServerPassword” value=“” />
        <!--  MAIL SERVER PORT
                If the SMTP server requires a custom port number, enter the value in this setting.
                The default value is: 25
          -->
        <setting name=“MailServerPort” value=“8025” />
        <!--  MAIL SERVER SSL
                If the SMTP server requires SSL, set the value to true.
                The default value is: false
        -->
```

If you are using default SendEmail action from Sitecore forms, it use **MainUtil.SendMail()**  method which use above settings :

```
 protected override bool Execute(SendEmailData data, FormSubmitContext formSubmitContext)
    {
      Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) formSubmitContext, nameof (formSubmitContext));
      using (MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage())
      {
        try
        {
          SendEmail.SetMessageAttributes(mailMessage, data, formSubmitContext);
          this.MailSender.SendMail(mailMessage);
          return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          this.Logger.LogError(ex.Message, ex, (object) this);
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
```

The MainUtil create SMTPClient using below code:

```
 private static SmtpClient CreateSmtpClient()
    {
      string mailServer = Settings.MailServer;
      SmtpClient smtpClient;
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(mailServer))
      {
        smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
      }
      else
      {
        int mailServerPort = Settings.MailServerPort;
        smtpClient = mailServerPort <= 0 ? new SmtpClient(mailServer) : new SmtpClient(mailServer, mailServerPort);
      }
      string mailServerUserName = Settings.MailServerUserName;
      smtpClient.EnableSsl = Settings.MailServerUseSsl;
      if (mailServerUserName.Length > 0)
      {
        string mailServerPassword = Settings.MailServerPassword;
        NetworkCredential networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(mailServerUserName, mailServerPassword);
        smtpClient.Credentials = (ICredentialsByHost) networkCredential;
      }
      return smtpClient;
    }
```